# git revert on single lines in single file of commit

Tags: git, github

I'm rather new to git and opened a pull request on github on a project containing some changes I did in my fork.
Now I need to revert a few changes on single lines of a single file in an earlier commit.

```
+-------+   +------+   +------+   +------+
|pullreq+<--+commit+<--+commit+<--+commit|
+-------+   +------+   +--+---+   +------+
                          ^
            +-------------+--------------+
            |1  some other peoples code  |
     undo-->+2         my changes        |
            |3  some other peoples code  |
     undo-->+4          my changes       |
            |5          my code          |
            +----------------------------+
```

Whats the easiest way to revert changes made to a single lines of an already commited change?

I'm also trying to preserve modification stamps of other people shown by git blame.

**//edit:**
I tested the following an it does not preserve the original modification stamp:
*foobar.sh contains lines commited by other people, I added new ones and changed existing ones, I need to revert changes made to single lines that I made changes to.*

```
git clone https://github.com/user/somerepo
cd somerepo
git blame -L 10,20 foobar.sh
nano foobar.sh
git add foobar.sh
git commit
git blame -L 10,20 foobar.sh
nano foobar.sh
git add foobar.sh
git commit
git blame -L 10,20 foobar.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a new commit which records the removal of those lines.

You can push that commit on the PR branch: it will be part of your pull request.

Comment: According to your answear, I tried (see edit in question), it didnt worked as I need since I'm trying to revert to a state where the last change to the line was made by someone else.

Comment: @hub it does not matter who did that last change: in your local cloned repo, make the right change (add/remove or modify lines), add, commit and push to your PR branch. A "revert" is a new commit (done by you) which reverts (cancel) older change (no matter who did those changes)